# Add event in google calendar from my web application

Tags: java, api, oauth-2.0

I need to add an event in google calendar for a specific user when an activity is added in my web application.

My application is developed in Java.

I read all the documentation on APIs and OAuth 2.0 but do not know where to start.

Help!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Start here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer
It will give you 90% of what you need to know